# Pine Script for loop

Tags: loops, pine-script

I'm trying to make a script where TradingView shows a label with all the results of the code. I really want a loop to get the code to catch all the data of multiple tickers (Heikin-Ashi charts). The code below doesn't work properly.

So, for every ticker, the loop needs to check if result = true; if so, then it needs the ticker to be added to the label:

```
s20ema = ema(close, 20)
s50sma = sma(close, 50)
s200sma = sma(close, 200)

scr_label = 'Screener: \n##########\n'

ticker_s1 = 'ADAUSDT'
ticker_s2 = 'ADXBTC'
ticker_s3 = 'AEBTC'
ticker_s4 = 'AGIBTC'
ticker_s5 = 'AIONBTC'

ha_period = "W" // Chart on which Master Direction is based
ha_open = security(heikinashi(ticker_s1), ha_period, open)
ha_close = security(heikinashi(ticker_s1), ha_period, close)

customFuncW() => (s20ema > s50sma) and (s50sma > s200sma) and (ha_close < ha_open)

s1  = security(ticker_s1,  'W', customFuncW())
s2  = security('ADXBTC',  'W', customFuncW())
s3  = security('AEBTC',  'W', customFuncW())
s4  = security('AGIBTC',  'W', customFuncW())
s5  = security('AIONBTC',  'W', customFuncW())

s = 1
for i = 0 to 5 
    s := s + 1
    scr_label := s[i] ? scr_label + ticker_s[i] + '\n' : scr_label  

lab_l = label.new(
    bar_index, -0.2, scr_label, 
    color=color.gray, 
    textcolor=color.black, 
    style =  label.style_labeldown,
    yloc = yloc.price)

label.delete(lab_l[1])

plot(0, transp = 100)
```

This code gives me an "undeclarer identifier 'ticker_s' " (the one in the for loop). Anybody has an idea?!

Comment: `s1` is not the same as `s[1]`, and `ticker_s1` is not equal to `ticker_s[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The for loop starta with variable i=0
so the first get s[0]

And there is no s0 declared
I think you should start with I=1